# Why has the Safe{WALLET} dapp iframe an outer scrollbar?

Tags: wallets, dapps, gnosis, safe

Just integrated the **Safe{WALLET}** with the [XPowermine.com](https://www.xpowermine.com) dapp and noticed that the `<iframe>` on the desktop has this *extra* scrollbar on the right hand side. Further, since the dapp has its own scrollbar it *really* looks ugly! Other **Safe{WALLET}** dapps' iframes seem also to posses this extra outer scrollbar.

Is it possible for the `<iframe>` to *not* have a scrollbar by default? Or at least it should be controllable by the `manifest.json` configuration.

[image: XPowermine.com in Safe{WALLET}]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for also posting this as [an issue](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/issues/2827) in our github. It's now fixed and will be released in 1.23.0.